# Django - specify template in view annotation

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to specif template name in view annotation.

I would like to do something like that in my views.py:
instead of:

```
def home(request, url):    
    page = PageFactory.create_for_url(url)    
    return render_to_response('front/home.html', {'page': page})
```

I would prefer to do it in this way:

```
@view('front/home.html')
def home(request, url):    
    page = PageFactory.create_for_url(url)    
    return {'page': page}
```

is it doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple home brewed decorators that do this

The following looks like a good start

```
def renderer(func):
        def wrapper(request, *args, **kw):
            output = func(request, *args, **kw)
            if isinstance(output, (list, tuple)):
                return render_to_response(output[1], output[0], RequestContext(request))
            elif isinstance(output, dict):
                return render_to_response(template, output, RequestContext(request))
            return output
        return wrapper
    return renderer
```

http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/821/

Google result yields 4-5.